# brcc32 produces Corrupted .RES file

Tags: delphi

I am building Delphi Projects from the command line and am using `brcc32.exe` to build the `.res` files.

I have added a number of custom strings to my `.RC` so it looks like this.  (There is a little Delphi5 app that prepares this .RC from a template)

```
1 VERSIONINFO 
 FILEVERSION 999,0,0,339
FILEOS VOS__WINDOWS32 
FILETYPE VFT_APP 
BEGIN  
 BLOCK "StringFileInfo" 
 BEGIN
  BLOCK "080904E4"
  BEGIN
   VALUE "FileDescription","Debug Build"
   VALUE "FileVersion","999.0.0.339"
   VALUE "LegalCopyright", "HuwCorp Finance Ltd"
   VALUE "Revision","339"
   VALUE "LastChangeRevision","335"
   VALUE "LastChangeDate","2013-06-07"
   VALUE "LastChangeTime","13:17:14"
   VALUE "LastChangeAuthor","foo1234"
   VALUE "BuildDate","12/06/2013"
   VALUE "BuildTime","10:36:59"
  END
 END
 BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
 BEGIN
   VALUE "Translation", 2057, 1252
 END
END
```

All well and good so far, but the `BRCC32` step produces a mangled `.res` file that looks like this (Viewed through a resource Builder)

```
  VALUE "LastChangeDate", "2013-06-074\x08\x01LastChangeTime"
  VALUE "LastChangeTime", "13:17:146\x07\x01LastChangeAuthor"
  VALUE "LastChangeAuthor", "foo1234"
  VALUE "BuildDate", "12/06/2013,\x08\x01BuildTime"
  VALUE "BuildTime", "10:36:59D"
```

And indeed clicking properties/Version on the built `.exe` shows the garbage characters e.g. BuildTime is displayed as `10:36:59D`

Can anyone suggest why ?

Comment: I am sure this is relevant, though I cannot exactly say what its significance is, but when I stick to 'standard' fields I can reproduce the problem merely by putting a longer string in the `CompanyName` field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StringTable resources need to be C-style null-terminated (even when using the Borland Resource Compiler).

Try this instead:

```
VALUE "FileDescription","Debug Build\0"
VALUE "FileVersion","999.0.0.339\0"
VALUE "LegalCopyright", "HuwCorp Finance Ltd\0"
VALUE "Revision","339\0"
VALUE "LastChangeRevision","335\0"
VALUE "LastChangeDate","2013-06-07\0"
VALUE "LastChangeTime","13:17:14\0"
VALUE "LastChangeAuthor","foo1234\0"
VALUE "BuildDate","12/06/2013\0"
VALUE "BuildTime","10:36:59\0"
```

Comment: @David: Thanks. The need for the first `\0` after the string name was one of the things I was going to check when I got to the office. :-)

Comment: Fab - sorted.  It is still odd though; my LegalCopyRight is hard-coded, and without the '\0' but it all works nicely.

Comment: @HughJones There's probably some padding bytes that happen to be zeros and you got (un)lucky. Ken is right though, you do need to null terminate the values.#

Comment: @David I did try that previously, but by adding a #0 to the string, to no effect.  Using the escape sequence is the answer.  Thanks, so much both of you.